# Different * selection strategies in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

What are the differences between the following approaches to target leaf nodes of a document based on some criteria?

```
<!-- using //* -->
//*[contains(@class, "w4")]       

<!-- using //node() -->
//node()[contains(@class, "w4")]

<!-- using //. -->
//.[contains(@class, "w4")]
```

All three of these 'work' to select the same node in some example xml, so I was wondering what if any difference there is between them, and if they're all the same, which is preferred (also why can't I just use `//[contains(@class, "w4")]` with an empty node, wouldn't `//` imply anywhere from the root node?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//*` selects all elements in the document.

`//node()` also selects other kinds of nodes (comments, text nodes, etc), but only elements are going to match a predicate that looks for attributes, so it ends up being equivalent.

`//.` is very unidiomatic, probably because it only works in XPath 2.0+ and doesn't do anything that you couldn't do some other way. I had to think about exactly what it means. It expands to `/descendant-or-self::node()/.`, which is equivalent to leaving out the `/.` at the end, which means that the only difference from `//node()` is that it also selects the root document node. But again, this isn't going to have any attributes, so it won't get past the predicate that tests @class.

The bottom line is that, in the presence of this predicate, they all do the same thing.

It's surprising how often people try `//[predicate]`, but it's completely ungrammatical. `//` on its own is like saying "select" without saying what you want to select; it's an unfinished sentence. And if you haven't said what you want to select, it doesn't make sense to then select a subset of it.

Comment: thanks for this answer.  One question regarding `//node()` -- only elements are going to match a predicate that looks for attributes, so it ends up being equivalent. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: //node() can select text nodes or comments, but text nodes and comments don't have attributes, so a predicate that looks for attributes like `[@class = 'abc']` will always be false for such nodes..